# Count of many to many and optimize query

Tags: django, python-3.x

I have a `Word` model
it has a many to many field to
`Phrase` model

I am passing my words to frontend in  `json` format fronend like this:

```
words_json = []

words = Word.objects.filter(....filter_by_some_params)

    for word in words:
      single_word_json = {}
      single_word_json['id'] = word.id
      single_word_json['name'] = word.name
      single_word_json['count'] = len(word.phrases.all())
      words_json.appen(word_json)

 return words_json
```

I feeel like this is not effective and doesn't scale (I will have up to 10k words and phrases, so what do I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following approach:

```
from django.db.models import Count

qs = Word.objects.filter(..).annotate(
    count=Count('phrase')
).values('id', 'name', 'count')
```

then your `words_json` is just:

```
words_json = list(qs)
```

The `.values()` will construct a queryset of dictionaries. Every dictionary will contain three items: `id`, `name`, and `count`. The `count` originates from the `.annotate(..)` function, where we count the number of `phrase`s.

The advantage of this is that we will do *all* processing in a single query like:

```sql
SELECT w.id, w.name, COUNT(wp.phrase_id)
FROM word AS w
LEFT OUTER JOIN word_phrase AS wp ON w.id = wp.word_id
GROUP BY w.id, w.name
```

So instead of *n+1* queries (with *n* the number of `Word`s that come out of the `.filter(..)`), we thus perform a single query. Furthermore we limit the bandwidth required for the database to return the results, and let Django wrap the response into dictionaries for us.

**EDIT**: In case a `Word` has a `ForeignKey` to a `Group`, and you want to include the name as well, you can write this as:

```
from django.db.models import Count, F

qs = Word.objects.filter(..).annotate(
    count=Count('phrase'),
    group_name=F('group__name')
).values('id', 'name', 'count', 'group_name')
```

Now every dictionary will have an extra key `group_name`. In case a `Word` has no `Group`, then the `group_name` will be `None` (or `null` in JSON).

Comment: One more question: If each word has a `foreign key`  to `Group` model, how can I also pass to my resulting list `'group.name` ?

Comment: So you want to include the name of the group in the JSON blob? Then you can perform an extra annotate, for example `group_name=F('group__name')` and include it in the `values`.

Comment: Ok, and the last question: if I need to pass an empty array to my resulting object - how can I do this, using annotate: `single_word_json['connected_words_to_check'] = []`

Comment: @user2950593: no, then you will have to manually patch every dictionary. But this will typically be fast, since there are no queries involved. It would actually -if that was possible - only be slower to annotate constants in a queryset.

Comment: What if I have an error: the annotation `group` conflicts with the field  group. Can I do something with this without renaming my resulting field ?

Comment: @user2950593: You can also put the `.values(..)` in front, and annotate, so `.values('id', 'name').annotate(group=F('group__name'))`.