# Excel extract function

Tags: excel

I'd like to extract the folder structure of an URL in excel. Lets say we have the following URL:

`https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51632630/count-of-many-to-many-and-optimize-query`

I'd like to extract the 2nd subfolder (51632630) with an excel formula. How do I realize this? Take in account:

- URLs can include https://, but also be added without https://

Thnx!

Answer (score 1):

If you are okay with it, this should work for both mentioned cases and potential `http`.

If data is in `A1` - formula in B1 would be:

```
=IF(LEFT(A1,4)="http",MID(A1, FIND("/", A1, FIND("/",A1, FIND("/", A1, FIND("//",A1)+1)+1)+1)+1,256),MID(A1, FIND("/", A1, FIND("/",A1, FIND("/", A1, FIND("/",A1)+1)+1)+1)+1,256))
```

And in `C1` would be:

```
=LEFT(B1,FIND("/",B1)-1)
```

It produces a following result:

```
| A                                                                     | B                                 | C         |
|---------------------------------------------------------------------  |---------------------------------  |---------- |
| https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51633071/excel-extract-function   | 51633071/excel-extract-function   | 51633071  |
| stackoverflow.com/questions/51633071/excel-extract-function           | 51633071/excel-extract-function   | 51633071  |
```

Comment: What i'd like to see is:

A - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51633071/excel-extract-function  
B - question
C - 51633071
D - excel-extract-function

And for some URLs there are 6 levels; how can I do this?

Comment: Well, the nested `FIND` is a way to go, and this creates a basic solution that you can edit per your need.

Answer (score 0):

You can use string manipulation functions SEARCH,MID and so on to archieve that.
See this nice blog about string splitting https://www.ablebits.com/office-addins-blog/2016/06/01/split-text-string-excel/

EDIT:
With the help of [How can I perform a reverse string search in Excel without using VBA?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/350264/how-can-i-perform-a-reverse-string-search-in-excel-without-using-vba), 
You can strip trailing words like this

- A1="https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51632630/count-of-many-to-many-and-optimize-query
- A2=SUBSTITUTE(A1,"/","|",LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"/","")))
- A3=RIGHT(A2, LEN(A2) - FIND("|",A2))
- A4=LEFT(A2, FIND("|",A2)-1)

Comment: Nice post, but I aint get it working. I'd like to have formulas for every level:
- questions
- 51632630

unfortunately it doesn't work :(

Answer (score 0):

With a udf?

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub test()
    MsgBox GetPathItem("https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51632630/count-of-many-to-many-and-optimize-query", 2)
End Sub
Public Function GetPathItem(ByVal path As String, ByVal position As Long) As String
    path = Replace$(path, "//", "##")
    GetPathItem = Replace$(Split(path, "/")(position), "##", "//")
End Function
```